# How to exclude node_modules from watchers files

Tags: angular-cli, watch, chokidar, angular-devkit

When I do `ng serve` the log shows errors like this:

```
Error from chokidar (/PATH_OF_MY_PROJECT/node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/PATH_OF_MY_PROJECT/node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg/ios-subway.svg'
```

I read that the solution is to change watchers file on Linux but that is a bad solution!

Why does Angular need to see changes to `node_modules`? It is a folder that doesn't change. If I need to install a new library I can restart the server.

Do not answer me if your solution is:
`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf`. I do not want to use this bad solution.

Comment: OP, did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and every answer pointed the solution you said.

> Doesnt answer me if your solution is: echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf

This didn't help me either.
I couldn't find a solution, but in webpack you can ignore/exclude the directories you don't want to check just doing the next thing inside your module.exports:

```
module.exports = {
      target: 'node',
      ...
      watchOptions: {
        ignored: [
          /node_modules/,
          ...
        ],
      },
```

Comment: what file did you try this in or did you find a solution?

Comment: but what if I don't have webpack??